# Check if it's active

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason javascript has stopped working on my project. To test this I added this code on the main index page to see if the alert would pop-up

```
@section scripts{
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            alert("working");
        });
    });
</script>}
```

**It didnt'.**

I have had some issues with my dependencies today. This is a view of my solutions explorer:

[image]

I have that alert on jQuery not installed, but it is (I guess this could be a bug).

But since my JS is not executing in any part of the project I checked NuGet, which says it was incompatible, and use NuGet

[image]

And this is where I am.

Any idea on the steps I should follow to make this work again?

Thanks in advance

**Note:**

Earlier I was receiving a lot of warning and an error about the JS files of other dependencies:

[image]

I uninstalled them because I believe they are not crucial for the project, but it was curious that all those alerts started to show at this point. Hoever, this dependencies restore when I reopen the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('hi');
```

That's the best way to test if your script is loading. I'm assuming you know how to open up your browsers console.

Some of the references to your packages may be broken, [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages). It gives directions on updating your packages with NuGet.

Lastly, the way you're importing your script is one I haven't seen before. Why not use:

```
<script src="/js/yourscript.js"></script>
```